# not initializing each time modal is loaded jQuery datepickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

See this link :
[jQuery datepickers not initializing each time modal is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745961/jquery-datepickers-not-initializing-each-time-modal-is-loaded)

I have exactly the same problem, given this solution, what Elements should I give these properties([data-toggle='open_modal']) on the page??

Comment: to element which triggers opening modal

Comment: <button type="submit" data-toggle='open_modal' onclick="$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));" class=" btn btn-primary save-button">save</button>     This element causes me to open the modal. I put these properties, but it does not apply at all

Comment: To have the problem described, you should already have a modal that opens automatically via bootstrap, most likely a `<div data-toggle="open-modal">` (note `-` not  `_`).  The solution the problem in your linked question is to add another toggle *to that same element* and have some code run on that new "toggle".

Comment: TBH that's a slightly strange/obscure solution to the problem.  If you're loading via ajax then you'll have a `success:` `.done()` callback - simply add the `.datepicker()` code into that callback (which the answer provides code for)- the `data-toggle=open_modal` seems like a red-herring.

Comment: Re: comment above (please add details to your question via [edit], not in comments).   It's not working because your button is added *after* the code in the linked answer `$("[data-toggle='open_modal']").click(function(event) {` runs - you need to use event delegation, change that to `$(document).on("click", "[data-toggle='open_modal']", function(event) {`

Comment: My Code link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70095546/how-to-load-javascript-css-files-in-partial-view